# SPO Management Shell not loading

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I've installed the SharePoint Online on a Windows 8.1 machine but am unable to get it working.  The console is able to detect the module has been installed but an Import-Module session returns the error below.

I'm running the console in administration mode so permissions shouldn't be an issue.  As this is my own personal machine I'd like to understand what this error means before I start messing about with certificates.

Any ideas on how to resolve are appreciated.
[image: SharePoint Online Management Shell Error in PowerShell]

Comment: Make sure you are running 64 bit version and run as administrator

Comment: You do not need to run PoSh as an Administrator. There is also a 32bit version of the SPO cmdlets, in which case you'd use 32bit PoSh.